# How to create the first version of database file from code EF Core

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I am new to EF Core 3.1.22 using it with my .NET 4.6 desktop application. I am able to create the database and migrations using the package manager console, but my code doesn't generate the database file on its own at first run, when the database doesn't exist yet.

If I create the database using `Update-Database` from the package manager console, the file is created.

How can I update this code to generate the database file from code at first run and then apply `database.migrate` on that?

```
public class MyDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>, IMyDbContextFactory
{       
    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($@"Data Source={DbConfiguration.GetDatabasePath()};", options =>
        {
            options.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
        });

        return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }

    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        var dbcontext=  CreateDbContext(new[] { "" });
        dbcontext.Database.Migrate();
        return dbcontext;
    }
}
```

Comment: try add context.Database.EnsureCreated() before migrate

Comment: @daremachine I tried that but then the Database.Migrate() throws exception that tables already exist. Also in the documentation of EnsureCreated() , it is mentioned that migration can not be applied on DB created by EnsureCreated().

Comment: Could you please add the DI configuration for your factory? The code as-is looks fine to me given the Mode didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I am sorry , it was a path issue but removing the mode did create the database. I will mark your reply as answer. Please add it.

Comment: I've undeleted the original answer now, glad it's resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string doesn't allow the database to be created, see the SQLite provider [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings#mode).

Either change it to `Mode=ReadWriteCreate` or remove it entirely as it's the default setting.